# How to fix Mat-Pagination labels being rendered on the bottom left of the screen?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, pagination

We are using Angular Material Design. For pagination I am using `<mat-paginator>`.

**The problem**: When a user hovers over one of the navigation buttons, or tries to select number of items per page, the corresponding labels are rendered on the **bottom left corner**.

I've followed the guide step by step from [Angular's material design docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#table-pagination), yet I get this bug. What might be the issue here? How can it be resolved?

Label after a user hovers on one of the navigation buttons. *Next page* in this case:

[image: Label after hovering on navigation buttons]

The label after a user chooses how many items per page to display:
[image]

How I'm using the paginator:

```
<mat-paginator 
  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20, 50, 100]"
  [pageSize]="10"
  showFirstLastButtons
  aria-label="Select page of vulnerable software">
</mat-paginator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out the problem. The issue is that I was missing the Angular material design global css theme. So in `angular.json` I just re-added           `"node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"` back to the styles array.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are missing material module import in module declaring your component.
Try importing this and add it to imports list of your module:

`import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator'`

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't that. I've imported the MatPaginatorModule in the shared.module and have provided it both in the imports and exports